# How to get the current url of QwebView?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

i use python and pyqt4 for web view.

here my simple code :

```
 import sys
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *
 from PyQt4.QtGui import *
 from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
 import os
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 web_view= QWebView()
 google='https://www.google.com'
 web_view.load(QUrl(google))
 web_view.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i want to create a new button where that button any time to execute i want to take current url text link and store it in some variable.

how to do that ?how to take current url from web view ?

Answer (score 2):

`QWebView` has the `url()` method that returns the current url, you must call it when you want to get the url.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
lay = QVBoxLayout(w)

button = QPushButton("Click Me")
web_view= QWebView()

lay.addWidget(button)
lay.addWidget(web_view)

def foo():
    print(web_view.url().toString())

button.clicked.connect(foo)

google='https://www.google.com'
web_view.load(QUrl(google))
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you are correct but I take something like this `PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://www.google.com')` if I `print` this as text is easy some way to take only the url like `https://www.google.com` ?